# Laravel - how do you SELECT WHERE LIKE?

Tags: php, select, laravel, sql-like

If i try `WHERE email = ?` it works, but if i try the code bellow it doesnt. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
DB::connection('operator')->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%?%'", array('test'));
```

This is how the `getQueryLog()` looks like.

```
  array(3) {
    ["query"]=>
    string(213) "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%?%'"
    ["bindings"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "test"
    }
    ["time"]=>
    float(1.45)
  }
```

Comment: Problem is if it is using PDO for binding then you get into problems because PDO automatically encloses the parameters in single quotes resulting in a query looking like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%'test'%'` when it executes the query on the server.

Comment: Why don't you use the Laravel ORM or QueryBuilder?

Comment: @ITroubs: that's not pdo's fault. placeholders cannot be quoted in the first place. `foo='?'` is a string literal question mark, `foo=?` is a placeholder.

Comment: @MarcB hmm you are right. My mistake.

Answer (score 25):

You have to put the `%` in the bindings array:

```
DB::connection('operator')
    ->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE ?", array('%test%'));
```

Also it would be a lot easier to just use Laravel's [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) or [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries)

For example that's what it would look like with the query builder:

```
DB::connection('operator')->table('users')->where('email', 'LIKE', '%test%')->get();
```

**Remember** to escape any `%` when using a string provided by the user! Like this:

```
$escapedInput = str_replace('%', '\\%', $input);
```

Comment: Right answer but i would still rather see you giving the OP the recomendation to use the query builder or a eloquent model with a scope

Comment: @ITroubs There you go :)

Comment: Right that's better ;-)

Comment: You have to remember to escape any `%` in the user-provided string.

Comment: @JosephSilber Good tip. I edited it in so it's better visible.

Comment: You should explain **how** to escape it :)

Comment: @JosephSilber I'm not entirely sure... is it `\%`?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I would never use an ORM and i find no reason to use the Query Builder.

Comment: @lukasgeiter - `str_replace('%', '\\%', $email)`

Comment: @nookie You're welcome. That's totally up to you. It's only my personal and ITroubs' recommendation...

Comment: @nookie By the way, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer to mark your question as solved.

Comment: I don't know about this engine, but in MySQL, you also need to escape `_` (underscores) - they can be special characters

Answer (score 7):

It's works perfect for me on laravel 5.7 like this :

```
$name = "the value that you want to find in the column";
Model::where("field", "LIKE", "\\" . $name . "%")->get()
```

`$name` is the part of string you want to find in the column with the concated with "%"

`"field"` is the field of the column
you can put "%" instead of "\"  ( % all chars)

```
$TheResult = MyModel::where("myFieldOfMyModel", "like", "%" . $name . "%")->get();
```

It's works perfect for me on laravel 5.7

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just escaping your variable works:

```
$name = "_";
Model::where("field", "LIKE", "\\" . $name . "%")->get()
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can you add more information on why? I can't seem to locate the double backslash functionality. Is that laravel specific?

Comment: I don't realy have a clear explanation, but that's what works for me